# Strange IE7 behaviors(or not)

Tags: html, css

I see no reason why this shouldn't work in all browsers, here is my css for anchor tag :

```
.myButton{
background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
border:1px solid #D8DFEA !important;
color:#3B5998;
cursor:pointer;
font-size:20px;
padding:10px;
}
```

Here is how it looks in IE7 :

[image]

And here is how it looks in other browsers :

[image]

HTML is nothing unusual as well :

```
<a href="#" class="myButton">Beta</a>
```

All of this is inside table, this anchor html is wrapped around with :

```
<tr>
   <td><a>...</a></td>
<tr>
```

I don't think this has to do it with anything but I mentioned it just in case, so the button is missing border top, any indications what might cause this?

Comment: try giving it a display: block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the usual `zoom:1;` isn't working try `float:left;` or `display: inline-block;vertical-align: top;` but the first thing id do is serving IE7 `margin-top:1px` or `position:relative;`.
You probably just need to trigger the magic HASLAYOUT.

As an alternative you could style the TD instead.